# DSP, random glitches resampling audio wave

Tags: audio, bluetooth, signal-processing, frequency, resampling

I'm using a DSP for audio processing, I get an audio input via Bluetooth (a2dp) and I output the processed audio through an analog connector to a headset.

The audio I receive from the Bluetooth device has a frequency of 44100 Hz, and one of the purposes of the DSP is to resample (upsample, downsample) the bluetooth audio to a frequency of my choosing, for example 48000 Hz.

I have already implemented the resampling (the manufacturer of the DSP has the code to do this) but I get random glitches in the output audio, and I have no idea why. The following images show a 400 Hz sine wave being played from the Bluetooth device to the analog output, being resampled from 44100 Hz to 48000 Hz, I connected a jack to this output and measured the resulting wave with an oscilloscope.

[image]

[image]

I can't find any patterns or something that tells me where to look. I've been trying to find the cause of this for over a week now and so far no success. Anyone have any ideas? I'm a bit desperate.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: are you sure that it's not the bluetooth part that's giving you trouble? Does a unresampled version of your signal show distortions? (Hint: maybe you can do something like arctan(current_sample/last_sample) which is the phase increase between these))

Comment: Well I also noticed that the sine wave in the images is not a 400 Hz sine wave, the original sine wave being played from the Bluetooth device has a frequency of 400 Hz. So another issue more. An unresampled version of the signal doesn't show any distortions, I think it might be the bluetooth part yes, as it performs some kind of sample rate adjustment when moving the samples to the DAC output.

Comment: Probably, you need to dither your output after the resampling.